Combine Entra ID user properties with devicename and deviceid in one table
I want to combine the following user properties with the associated devicename and deviceID for some user accounts in one Table:
'Id','DisplayName','Mail','UserPrincipalName','Department','JobTitle','AccountEnabled','LastPasswordChangeDateTime','Licenses','LastLogonDateTime'
For now, I have three different querys and therefore three different tables. The goal is, to combine this into one table.
I am not so much experienced with powershell and hope to get an answer here. I don' think this is that much difficult, but I stuck to find a connection between Get-MgUser and Get-intunemanageddevice and Get-AzureADDevice.
# Build the props array
    $props = @(
        # Basic metadata
        'Id','DisplayName','Mail','UserPrincipalName','Department','JobTitle'
        # Account Status
        'AccountEnabled',
        # Password last set
        'LastPasswordChangeDateTime',
        # Last logon
        'SignInActivity',
        # Assigned Licenses
        'AssignedLicenses'
    )
    
# list of all user account that have been assigned any of your licensing plans and UPN
    $mgUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "assignedLicenses/`$count ne 0 and startsWith(UserPrincipalName,'xyz')" -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable licensedUserCount -All -Property $props | Select-Object $props
    
    $skus = Get-MgSubscribedSku
    
    
    $skuHt = @{}
    foreach ($sku in $skus) {
        $skuHt[$sku.SkuId] = $sku
    }
    
    $userOutput = foreach ($user in $mgUsers) {
    
# Resolve the ID to license name
        $licenses = foreach($license in $user.AssignedLicenses) {
            $skuHt[$license.SkuId].SkuPartNumber
        }
    
# Get the last logon date
        $lastLogon = $user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
    
# Add the new properties
        $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastLogonDateTime -Value $lastLogon
        $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Licenses -Value ($licenses -join ',')
    
# Remove the unneeded ones
        $user | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty AssignedLicenses -Property 'Id','DisplayName','Mail','UserPrincipalName','Department','JobTitle','AccountEnabled','LastPasswordChangeDateTime','Licenses','LastLogonDateTime'
    }
    
    $userOutput | Export-Excel C:\tmp\Check_Users.xlsx -TableName 'xyz_Users' -WorksheetName xyz-User -AutoSize
    
    
    $ADMDevices = get-intunemanageddevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages | where "devicename" -like 'pc-xyz*' | Select-object deviceName, userid, UserPrincipalName #|ft
    $ADMDevices | Export-Excel C:\tmp\Check_Users.xlsx -TableName 'Users_DeviceName' -WorksheetName DeviceName -AutoSize
    
    
    $devices = $ADMDevices.deviceName
    $DeviceID = foreach ($device in $devices) {
    
        Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString $device | select DisplayName,ObjectId,deviceid
    }
    $DeviceID | Export-Excel C:\tmp\Check_Users.xlsx -TableName 'Users_DeviceID' -WorksheetName DeviceID -AutoSize

